# Replace windows with linux

Tags: linux, windows, elementaryos

I have decided to replace windows 8.1 with linux elementary os.
But, seems like every where people talking about dual boot with windows but i want to replace windows so what should be the process:

- Start normal installation
- Choose Something else
- Format or Clean only the C drive and install elementary on that drive?
- Will it be able to make use of other partitions on the hard drive

Notice that i want to format only the C drive and other drives should be unchanged.
So, how should i replace windows 8.1 with elementary os?

Comment: It does not really matter.  If you choose to install Linux on partition that Windows exists on then Windows will be deleted and be replaced by Linux.  Just follow the installation procedure for the Linux distribution in question.

Comment: I don't see the exact question here – it seems you listed all the steps already?

Comment: @slhck - The question was suppose to be.  "Out of those 4 options which one should I us?" or I believe that to be the question.

Comment: Just in case you want to come back and think of dual boot:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WulgG1GeJ4U

Answer (score 1):

First you may want to disable secure boot in the BIOS as getting any OS other than Windows working with it is unneeded pain.

Boot from your installation media (DVD or USB containing the Linux distribution you want to install).

When asked about the destination drive for installation and file-system mount points, you will see one UEFI partition at the head of the disk, a 100MB partition after it (Windows bootloader), and the main partition for Windows (labeled C:), in addition to the rest of your drives and partitions.

Choose to delete the 100MB partition and the partition after it (C:).

Now, choose to format the empty space to a new partition with file-system `ext4` and size of C: + 100MB - 2 * RAM, where RAM is the amount of RAM in your computer. Set the mount point of this partition to `/` (root). Format the remaining space as a `swap` partition.

This should do what you want. If you want, you can also separate the main partition to have a separate `/boot` partition before it just in case something fails in the future (but this is not mandatory).